# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.basicscodelab.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I already tried multiple solutions on other posts related to this issue but none of them solved my problem.
Every time I try to run the app it retrieves the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.basicscodelab.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Wsdppue-dtMOBrCy74DHxg==/com.example.basicscodelab-YWEUk1F6M5wI7edqOWQ5WQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Wsdppue-dtMOBrCy74DHxg==/com.example.basicscodelab-YWEUk1F6M5wI7edqOWQ5WQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]`

My Build.gradle Project Level

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcK32.png)

My Build.gradkle App Level

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXZsC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vSgt.png)

I've also tried to build the project from scratch again and just paste the code, but it didn't solved the issue.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post code or JSON data in screen shots. Copy the content, paste it into your question and format it as code. Screen shots are bad to read and you can not search text in them.

Comment: Also link or write the solutions you have already tried so they don't get proposed again

Comment: Did you check that the manifest has the activity declared without errors? sometimes the package is wrong and you can get errors because of that.

Comment: @LuisPascual thank you for your remember, forgot to check that, it solved my issue!